# Is it Possible for img to resize the width and height according to the screen size?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a problem with css and responsiveness i think my website is responsive enough, but the only thing make me confused is the img on my slider.

here is my website : www.spc.id

the img on slider is not responsive i think, because it does not friendly on mobile screen.

i have tried with media queries for resize the width and height:

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 639px) and (min-width: 480px){
#home-hero{
    width: 480px;
    height: auto;
    padding:90px;
  }
}

</style>
```

i can customize the height , but why i cannot custom the width ?
Thanks if you do not mind to helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without more information, but I notice a couple of things in the source code of your site.

1) Your media query is syntactically correct, but its not clear why you have a min-width rule on it. Unless you have another media query for screens smaller than 480px in width, you should eliminate the min-width rule. Try this code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 639px){
#home-hero{
    width: 480px;
    height: auto;
    padding:90px;
  }
}
```

You can play around with this jsfiddle which should hopefully clarify what I mean. https://jsfiddle.net/8nzatewL/

2) Looks like you're using bootstrap, but you have a typo in your class name. Change:

```
<div class='contai ner'>
```

to:

```
<div class='container'>
```